# Problem with the rendering of text, menus, and icons

Tags: drivers, 20.04, icons, fonts, intel-graphics

I have a problem with the rendering of text and icons. Sometimes the problem disappears as suddenly as it appeared. There are times when I don't have the problem at all. It helps as I hover my mouse over the pixelated icon/text/part of the window. When I open up a new window/program they don't have pixelated objects.

[image: picture of the bug]

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 in Lenovo Thinkpad T420 with integragated Intel graphics card.
I have i915 graphics driver installed.

> ```
>    description: VGA compatible controller
>    product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
>    vendor: Intel Corporation
>    physical id: 2
>    bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>    version: 09
>    width: 64 bits
>    clock: 33MHz
>    capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>    configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
>    resources: irq:30 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded to Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 from a previous version, then you may need to "delete" a file or remove some drivers. Let's start with the simpler option:

**1 — Remove a `.conf` file**

Sometimes this issue is caused by an old xorg configuration file. We can temporarily rename it to see if the problem is resolved and, if everything works well, delete the unnecessary file later.

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Change the name of your `20-intel.conf` file to something else:

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.old
   ```
2. Reboot

If the problem is resolved, you can delete the `20-intel.old` file at your leisure. If something unexpected happens, you can rename the file back to `20-intel.conf` to restore previous functionality.

**2 — Remove the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package**

Some people have found that removing the video driver will force Ubuntu to (re)install something that works better. To do this, you need to remove the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package.

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Remove the video driver:

   ```
   sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
   ```
2. Reboot

If everything is good, then you can enjoy proper visual clarity again. If things stay the same, then the OS re-installed the same browser and the issue is unrelated to the most common symptoms for this problem.

***Note:** Some people using Dell notebooks have had to do both of these things to resolve their issue. If neither option works in isolation, consider trying both.*